# jQuery click event style sheet changing not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

jQuery click event style sheet changing not working.I am trying to change the style sheet using jQuery, The style sheet is changing but style sheet properties are not working. How can I solve this issue.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".theme1").click(function() {
$("#switch").attr({href : "theme1.css"});
});
});
```

Comment: even it working, you need a reload to apply new CSS! and this is not a correct way to change css!

Comment: @jiff, `reload` ? Reload will reset `css` I guess!

Comment: On click you want to change your stylesheet, right? browser how to detect must update your styles?

Comment: @jiff 3   can you suggest a good method

Comment: Yes, I will update my answer

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
$('#toggleStyle').click(function (){
   $('link[href="style.css"]').attr('href','styleNew.css');
});
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wnn7tqbk/1/)**

just if you want to keep new style if user do a reload, you should set a cookie to keep user setting.

---

**Multi CSS with select option:**

```
$('#ChangeStyle').change(function (){
    var val = $(this).val();
   $('link[rel="stylesheet"]').attr('href',val+'.css');
});
```

**Html:**

```
<select id="ChangeStyle">
  <option value="Style1">Style 1</option>
  <option value="Style2">Style 2</option>
  <option value="Style3">Style 3</option>
</select>
```

---

**Multi CSS with buttons:**

```
$('.toggleStyle').each(function (){
$(this).click(function (){
    var rel = $(this).attr('rel');
   $('link[rel="stylesheet"]').attr('href',rel+'.css');
});
});
```

**Html:**

```
<a class="toggleStyle" rel="Style1">Style 1</a>
<a class="toggleStyle" rel="Style2">Style 2</a>
<a class="toggleStyle" rel="Style3">Style 3</a>
<a class="toggleStyle" rel="Style4">Style 4</a>
<a class="toggleStyle" rel="Style5">Style 5</a>
```

Comment: It just solve your problem in question, I mean it will change your stylesheet, but as i told you in comment will not load your new style. I will update my post with good method.

Comment: @kannanD.S I tested this , It working fine, no need to use other method.

Comment: @ jiff yes its working, i have one more doubt. if i have 5 style sheets  then how this code works

Comment: Well it's possible too. but it depend your `html` , you have drop down for changing style? or just are links? @kannanD.S

Comment: @ jiff 1  just 5 buttons(like color picker)

Comment: in your last example it is replacing other style sheets also

Comment: @kannanD.S I don't understand, we wanted to replace other stylesheet, wasn't it?

Comment: @ jiff  is there is other style sheets in that page then thats also replacing

Comment: ok i got it, use this `$('link[href="style.css"]').attr('href','styleNew.css');` or set id for it `$('#switch').attr('href','styleNew.css');`  @kannanD.S

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
<head><link id="test" href="yourstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /></head>
```

Jquery::

```
​$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".theme1").click(function() {
  $("#test").attr("href", "newStyle.css");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can update the new style-sheet by updating your `<link>` and appedning it to the `<head>` as follow:

```
$('<link/>', {rel: 'stylesheet', href: 'style1.css'}).appendTo('head');
```

See the [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/jCzXvHpgTqr5KFf6JpIM?p=preview)

Here the `h1` has `color:red` which changes to `green` as the style-sheet source is changed from `style.css` to `style1.css` on clicking the `change style` button.

Here is the html code:

```
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script data-require="jquery" data-semver="2.2.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <a class="clickToStyle">change Style</a>
  </body>

</html>
```

It has **style.css** as the original css.

In the JS:

```
$(document).on('click','.clickToStyle',function(){
  $('<link/>', {rel: 'stylesheet', href: 'style1.css'}).appendTo('head');
})
```

The stylesheet source is replaced with **style1.css** and hence new styles get applied.

Comment: ithink this method is not possible, why because it always appending on each click and  if we have multiple stylesheets then what happens?

Comment: can  you provide a fiddle

Comment: you can give class to your link say 'link1' and then use the above method for updating as "$('.link1').attr('href', 'style1.css').appendTo('head');" See the plunkr "https://plnkr.co/edit/2QQAm8dm7voJZoAgfOmq?p=preview"

Comment: I have already provided a plunkr. see line no. 4 of the answer